# Adding synchronized lyrics to songs

Tags: windows, mp3, media-player, lyrics

I want to start something like a personal [TuneWiki](http://www.tunewiki.com/) on my computer. I'm using Windows and have a lot of MP3s.

Now I want to add lyrics to them for personal use. I tried Windows Media Player but it is bit a hard to synchronize all of the text with the song time.

Are there other tools or players for adding lyrics so that when I start to play a song the streaming text will be synchronized with the beat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been using [minilyrics](http://www.crintsoft.com/) for quite a while now and it is great at downloading the lyrics automatically, and many of them are already syncronized.  It has a lyrics editor where you can enter time codes (ie minutes and seconds) for each line.  It's not free -$14.95.

As a freeware option i can reccomend [evillyrics](http://www.evillabs.sk/evillyrics/) which works similarly to minilyrics.  The interface is a bit rough and can be a little buggy at times but pretty good.  Their song database is not huge but if you are willing to do it yourself you should be quite happy with it.

Both options work in conjunction with many media player programs including WMP, iTunes, Foobar2000, WinAMP and several others

Answer (score 2):

You can install minilyrics as a plugin to [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/addons/general/) which I've found to be an excellent free music player, library organiser and CD ripper.

This page also suggests evillyrics too.